# how do you use a UIbutton In a struct for segue

Tags: swift, struct, uibutton, segue

im very new to Swift and apple so sorry if this is a bad question.
im using a table view and xib a xib file to populate the cells. i need a button in the cells to segue to a viewcontroller and pass an Int to a global value. i learned that you cant use a func for this. so what is the correct method? 
Below is what i tried

```
 struct scale {
    let cell : Int!
    let name : String
    let og : String
    let fg : String
    let abv : String
    let date : String
    let image : UIImage
    let button : UIButton
}



class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var scaleView1 = [scale]()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        scaleView1 = [scale(cell : 1, name : "test1", og : "11", fg : "11", abv : "11", date : "11-11-1111", image:  imageLiteral(resourceName: "live-preview-potato"),button : segueFunc(i: 0)),
                      scale(cell : 1, name : "test2", og : "22", fg : "22", abv : "22", date : "22-22-2222", image:  imageLiteral(resourceName: "live-preview-potato")),
                      scale(cell : 1, name : "test23", og : "232", fg : "223", abv : "223", date : "322-22-2222", image:  imageLiteral(resourceName: "live-preview-potato")),
                      scale(cell : 1, name : "test1", og : "11", fg : "11", abv : "11", date : "11-11-1111", image:  imageLiteral(resourceName: "live-preview-potato"))]

    }

    func segueFunc(i: Int){
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "ViewController2", sender: nil)
        thing = i
    }
```

Comment: I would advise to add that `Button` into your custom cell instead

Comment: Hello, welcome to iOS world. I suggest you take some time to learn the fundamentals such as how to use a `UITableView` properly. A simple search on Google would help you to find an extensively written tutorial, such as http://www.thomashanning.com/uitableview-tutorial-for-beginners/ ... Also, if you really need a button inside your `UITableViewCell`s, then you should add `selectors` to that or use `delegates`. Good luck.

Comment: And your approach to passing data is wrong this will be never work you need to process the sending of data in the prepareForSegue method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to IOS developement world. A common way to communicate between views and your controllers is **target/action** concept. In your example, you want to target your UIButton (=view) and perform a segue by clicking on this button (= action handled by your controller). After the main explanation, you need to this :

1. Add your UIButton to your custom cells.
2. Add an action to perform the segue on your UIButton like this :

   `button.addTarget(target: self, action: #selector(segueFunc), for controlEvents: .touchUpInside)`. So you are saying please add me, the button, as a target of the action `segueFunc` when there is a touchUpInside event occuring (= when user clicks on it)
3. Implement your function `segueFunc` like you do but **you can't pass any parameter** :
   `func segueFunc(){ 
       performSegue(withIdentifier: "ViewController2", sender: nil)
    }`
4. Finally, you need to implement the function `prepare` to prepare the transition to your next view controller. In this method, you are going to pass data like your int and whatever you want : 
   `func prepare(for segue:UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)`